# Check that python list follows a specific repeating pattern

Tags: python, testing, pattern-matching

I have a python list which contains only two symbols, let us say they are `a` and `b` and the list looks like so:

```
l = ['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b']
```

Now in my application, I have thousands of these lists, and they vary in length (typically a few hundred long). But what they all have in common is that they have the repeating pattern `(a,b)`. This list, for example, is broken:

```
l_broken = ['a','b','b','a','a','b','a','b','a','a','a','b','a','b','b','a']
```

Anything which deviates from the `a,b` repeating pattern in `l` must be considered broken. Even if the list is not of even length, then it is broken. So this must be a very strict test. But essentially if the list `l` is of length `N` then it means that `(a,b)` has to repeat itself `N/2` times. The symbols `a` and `b` are the only things that will ever appear in these lists, so checking for that is not required since it is inconceivable in this application, for anything else to be seen.

I should say that they all *should* have the *first* pattern. I am looking for an efficient way, a test, that can determine that each list does, in fact, have this repeating pattern. And if not throw an error or something e.g.

```
assert my_fancy_test(l), 'the list does not follow the correct pattern'
```

I think I am looking for sub-sequence matching, but my google searches are coming up short.

### EDIT:

Thank you all for your excellent solutions. I had no idea you could do even half of these. Great stuff. I added a short performance overview at the end for you to peruse.

Comment: `one_list in another_list`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght You could do `assert [a,b] in L` but I need to know that this pattern is in fact repeated in the whole list.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest not sure what you mean, my list only contains two symbols, that repat themselves in the aforementioned pattern.

Comment: Are the actual symbols strings? Or are you just using them to represent the issue?

Comment: @tituszban they are actual strings but I am happy to replace with something else if that is easier. They are just a placeholder really for an operation that happens.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am really sorry, I don't know you mean. I am trying to figure out if the pattern `a,b` repeats itself as required in all of `L`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands well there's a nice one-liner -- feel free to add it as an answer so other people can have a look too. It's very elegant.

Comment: Is `['a', 'b', 'a']` still valid? Or is it required to have an even number of elements, starting with `'a'`

Comment: @tituszban no that would be invalid, the specific pattern is `[a,b]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple test function based on list multiplication:

```
def test_repeating_pattern(lst, pat):
    pat_len = len(pat)
    assert len(lst) % pat_len == 0, 'mismatched length of list'
    assert list(pat) * (len(lst) // pat_len) == lst, 'the list does not follow the correct pattern'
    print(lst, 'is valid')


L = ['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b']
L_broken = ['a','b','b','a','a','b','a','b','a','a','a','b','a','b','b','a']
```

Testing:

```
test_repeating_pattern(L, ('a', 'b'))
['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'] is valid
```

---

```
test_repeating_pattern(L_broken, ('a', 'b'))
AssertionError: the list does not follow the correct pattern
```

Answer (score 3):

### Here is what you need to check

**Are there any other symbols in your list and the length of your list is divisable by 2:**

```
assert len(l) == l.count('a') + l.count('b') and len(L) % 2 == 0
```

**And there are no repeat of the symbols:**

```
j = ''.join(l)
assert 'aa' not in j and 'bb' not in j
```

**The first item in your list is `'a'`**

```
assert 'a' is L[0]
```

If they all pass, that must mean, that you only have your two symbols, and two subsequent symbols are never the same

Comment: I'm not sure that iterating 3 times over `i` and then 2 times over `j` is a very efficient approach.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel It's the second most efficient solution after [RomanPerekhrest's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116855/4441404). It's in fact 4 times more efficient than the next one, which is by [h4z3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116750/4441404)

Comment: This will incorrectly validate `['b', 'a', 'b', 'a']` as non-broken when it should be considered broken as it does not follow the pattern of `(a, b)` as required by the OP..

Answer (score 3):

## Performance

Test list: `l = ['a','b']*100000`

[RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116855/3126402)'s solution:

```
CPU times: user 636 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 636 µs
Wall time: 639 µs
```

[GZ0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58117040/3126402)'s answer:

```
CPU times: user 14.6 ms, sys: 78 µs, total: 14.7 ms
Wall time: 13.9 ms
```

[Silveris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116780/3126402)' answer:

```
CPU times: user 95.2 ms, sys: 3.95 ms, total: 99.1 ms
Wall time: 98 ms
```

[h4z3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116750/3126402)'s answer:

```
CPU times: user 39.9 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 39.9 ms
Wall time: 38.6 ms
```

[tituszban](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116667/3126402)'s answer:

```
CPU times: user 2.71 ms, sys: 46 µs, total: 2.76 ms
Wall time: 2.76 ms
```

[ruso_ro1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116940/3126402) answer:

```
CPU times: user 32.4 ms, sys: 3.35 ms, total: 35.8 ms
Wall time: 34.7 ms
```

[Elias Strehle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58118200/3126402)

```
CPU times: user 11.7 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 11.7 ms
Wall time: 12.1 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_fancy_test(my_list):
    pattern = ['a', 'b']
    if not len(my_list) % len(pattern) == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
        if not my_list[i] == pattern[i % len(pattern)]:
            return False
    return True
```

Pattern can be any list of any length (universal solution).

Only checks full pattern (e.g. a,b,a will fail) and pattern has to start from the beginning (e.g. b,a,b will fail as well).

```
L = ['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b']
assert my_fancy_test(L) #passes
L2 = ['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','c']
assert my_fancy_test(L2) #fails
```

Answer (score 1):

One method could be to first make pairs:

```
>>> l = ['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b']
>>> pairs = [[l[i], l[i + 1]] for i in range(0, len(l) - 1, 2)]
>>> pairs
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
```

And then count the occurences of `['a', 'b']` in the list of pairs and compare it to half of the size of the list:

```
>>> pairs.count(['a', 'b']) == len(l) / 2
True
```

It would look like:

```
def my_fancy_test(l):
    pairs = [[l[i], l[i + 1]] for i in range(0, len(l) - 1, 2)]
    return pairs.count(['a', 'b']) == len(l) / 2
```

PS: Please note that according to PEP8, uppercase names should only be for constants.

Comment: Sorry I mean constants, not global variables... If you want to read more about it: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
pattern = ['a', 'b']

p_len = len(pattern)
assert all(pattern == L[i: i + p_len] for i in range(0, len(L), p_len))
```

you take chunk by chunk of the size of the pattern and you test against the pattern

for example:

```
pattern = ['a', 'b']

p_len = len(pattern)
l_broken = ['a','b','b','a','a','b','a','b','a','a','a','b','a','b','b','a']
all(pattern == l_broken[i: i+p_len] for i in range(0, len(l_broken), p_len))
```

output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-160-edf435d855b9> in <module>
      1 p_len = len(pattern)
      2 l_broken = ['a','b','b','a','a','b','a','b','a','a','a','b','a','b','b','a']
----> 3 assert all(pattern == l_broken[i: i+p_len] for i in range(0, len(l_broken), p_len))

AssertionError:
```

Comment: You should check for existing answers. [RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116855/4441404) already posted this.

Comment: Sure. His is in a function. But functionally it's the exact same. It's the functionality that matters, not how it's packaged.

Comment: Yes, the obvious performance difference is 0.29% (on 160000000 length list)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to join the list and use regular expressions for pattern matching:

```
import re

def is_broken(input_list, pattern = re.compile("(?:ab)*")):
    return pattern.fullmatch(''.join(input_list)) is None

print(is_broken(['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b']))
print(is_broken(['a','b','b','a','a','b','a','b','a','a','a','b','a','b','b','a']))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

This approach can also be used to match some more complex patterns efficiently or extracting information while matching patterns.

Answer (score 0):

A list is *correct* if and only it satisfies the following four requirements:

- The list has at least one entry
- The last entry is `b`
- Every entry with an even index is `a`
- Every entry with an odd index is `b`

```
def is_correct_entry(idx, v):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        return v == 'a'
    else:
        return v == 'b'

def my_fancy_test(l):
    return l and l[-1] == 'b' and all(is_correct_entry(idx, v) for idx, v in enumerate(l))
```

This code might have a speed advantage because it does not create new lists, avoids costly `len` computations and does not check the remainder of the list if it finds an incorrect entry (check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) for the `all` built-in method).

Comment: Test it with `l = ['b', 'a'] + ['a', 'b'] * 100000` ;-) Thanks for the fun brain teaser!

Comment: Ha, that's interesting: `CPU times: user 6 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 6 µs; Wall time: 7.63 µs` -- so what's happening here then?

Comment: As soon as you see the first entry (`'b'`) you know that the list must be incorrect. So you can stop checking and just return `False`. This is what my code does by using the `all` method. All other solutions check the _entire_ list in some way or another, even if the first entry is already incorrect.

Comment: @EliasStrehle rusu_ro1's solution does not check the entire list. Technically my solution also does not *check* the entire list but it has to build a string from the list so you could say it needs to traverse the full list. If the input is originally from a full string then that could be avoided.